# Trigger Azure Function via WebProxy HTTP request

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible, and if not why, for an Azure Function to be triggered through a `WebProxy` (function URL or function proxy endpoint) specified as part of a `HttpClient` or `WebRequest`?

I tried doing so (.NET sample code below), but it keeps throwing an exception: `ProtocolError -- The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found`, even though the function works on direct access in the browser.

Client:

```cs
var proxy = new WebProxy("test-proxy.azurewebsites.net");
:
:
await httpClient.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/html");
```

Function (test-proxy.azurewebsites.net):

```cs
public static async Task<string> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: You want test-proxy.azurewebsites.net to act as a HTTPS proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: Azure Functions don't support `CONNECT` HTTP method, which is required for proxy connections, so it won't work.

Comment: Where did you discover this information? I'm also trying to do this, but am getting a 404.